# Replace pod IP address with Host IP address keeping path and port same

Tags: regex, prometheus

Currently I am monitoring Kubernetes Pods using Prometheus. My base config is :

```
- job_name: 'kubernetes_pods'
  tls_config:
    insecure_skip_verify: true
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - api_server: http://k8s_master:8080
    role: pod
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
      action: replace
      target_label: pod_name
    - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
      action: replace
      target_label: __metrics_path__
      regex: (.+)
```

This basically results the Endpoints column stating the internal Kubernetes IP addresses rather than the host IP addresses on which the pods are deployed.

[image]

I want to change the pod IP addresses to the actual host IP addresses.

So I added the below config:

```
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_host_ip]
  target_label: __address__
  regex: (.*)
  replacement: $1
```

Now what Im seeing is that the IPs have definitely been changed but for some reason everything after `:` is exactly the same which is wrong.

[image]

Is there something wrong with the regex ?

Answer (score 2):

`__address__` includes the port number, so you'll need to either preserve that or take it from another label. For example:

```
- source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_host_ip, __address__]
  target_label: __address__
  regex: (.*);.*:(\d+)
  replacement: $1:$2
```

Comment: Thanks. But I assume this will work only if my metrics path is same right i.e. /metrics ? My different pods have different metrics paths e.g. /pod-name/health.

Comment: That's controlled by the `__metrics_path__` label, which is independant